# Chinese characters on original Art (Painting and Litho on Wood) I bought in China

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification

Does anyone know what the chinese characters say on these pictures? I bought them in China while visiting a few years ago and everyone always asks me what they mean. I love them but would love to know what they actually say - - assume it says what is in the painting but can anyone help me on this? Four pictures with Each picture depicting a stage of farming food. ...sorry i do not have them in the right order but very clear which picture is for which farming season.

[image: Harvest]
[image: Planting seeds]

[image: Prepare Soil]
[image: Celebrate the harvest]

Comment: I for one think they are too elaborate to be pictograms.

Comment: Which characters? These look more like actual pictures.

Comment: They look like cave painting inspired modern art

Comment: It was the characters at the top of each picture i was wondering about.I thought they were rather strange for language characters as well but I thought maybe it was an old form of one of the chinese languages or something.  Thanks everyone for your help and thoughts

Comment: Is it perhaps [Dongba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongba_symbols) from the [Naxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxi_language) language? Maybe you bought it in [Lijiang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijiang)?

Comment: My gosh! i think you are right. I could not remember where bough tit in china and in retracing my steps of a 3 month trip back in 2005 i completely forgot I was in Lijiang  - I had to look it up and remembered it right away and why we went there. WOW! thank you so much for figuring this out - you helped L. Parker find the other info below! I am going to treasure these piece of art even more and will create info to put on the back of them so I can tell people more about them now.  You have no idea what this means to me so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Mou某's excellent observation, I looked up a copybook of Naxi pictographs (He 2003) and was able to identify the following:

0. The pictographs (Dongba script) are the writing system of the [Naxi language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxi_language).
1. **The pictographs on the left are the four seasons. They are compound ideographs.**

   |  | Compound ideograph | Components = <sup>[image: sky]sky</sup> + | Pronunciation |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Spring | [image: spring] | <sup>[image: wind]wind*</sup> | mɯ33 ɲi21 |
   | Summer | [image: summer] | <sup>[image: rain]rain</sup> | mɯ33 ʐu21 |
   | Autumn | [image: autumn] | <sup>[image: flower]flower</sup> and <sup>[image: land]land</sup> | mɯ3[3] tʂʰv̩55 |
   | Winter | [image: winter] | <sup>[image: snow]snow</sup> | mɯ33 tʂʰɹ̩31 |

   So spring means 'the season of wind', summer 'the season of rain', autumn 'the season of flowers blossoming', and winter 'the season of snow' (Fang 1981:106-107).
2. **The pictographs on the right are human activities. They should correspond with the seasons.†**

   | Collocated with | Pictogram | Pronunciation | Meaning |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | Spring | [image: sow] | pʰv̩55 | to sow |
   | Summer‡ | [image: channel water] | ʂɻ̩21 | to channel water |
   | Autumn | [image: pull out] | pər21 | to pull out (crops) |
   | Winter‡ | [image: sing] | dzər33 | to sing |

**Footnotes**

* According to Fang (1981:106).

† In particular, those with a pointy hat [image: woman] mean they are women.

‡ I am not sure if these are the correct pictograms.

**References**

1. 和力民（2003）納西象形文字字帖。昆明：雲南民族出版社。
2. 方國瑜（1981）納西象形文字譜。昆明：雲南人民出版社。

Comment: Although, I would perhaps disagree with the statement *they are too elaborate to be pictograms of Chinese*. Shang/Zhou bronzes have glyphs which are quite amusing - [this one](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=62278), I believe, is a clan icon.

Comment: @dROOOze thanks. I never knew this! It’s just that the Dongba script strikes me as being more “Egyptian hieroglyphic” (not “elaborate”) than the usual oracle scripts in Chinese.

Comment: WOW you all are amazing!! i searched like you would not believe trying to figure all of this out and what you have figured out together is amazing! all i can do is say WOW, AMAZING AND THANK YOU!.

Answer (score 0):

They are 象形文字 (Hieroglyphs) inspired modern art

Too much information in these drawings to be a simple character. They are more a story than words

1. Either a river flows from a mountain or rain fell from a cloud,  and a person is digging the soil with a hoe
   [image]
2. Either a river flows from a mountain or a field near the mountain,  and a person is planting seeds
   [image]
3. looks like a person with a headdress or sun hat (Priest or farmer) is offering rice plant to an altar or a temple
   [image]
4. either a picture of people keeping birds (chicken maybe) or people storing grains in a storage house
   [image]

These drawings depict the development of a farming community